# How do I pass variables from one function to another and use them in conditional statements in python?

Tags: python, function, variables, conditional-statements, parameter-passing

I'm new to programming in general and even newer to python.  I'm only a couple of days into it.  I'm working on a problem that I know is simple, but the more I tinker with it, the worse it seems to get.

essentially what I am trying to do is create a variable from a conditional in function a that I can pass to other functions.  I've been trying to do this to create like character creation screens in the world's simplest RPG.  However, as simple as the game is, I quickly got in over my head.  I decided to keep the spirit of what I'm after, but with an easier example.

Now, I'm simply trying to put a meal together.

```
def entree():
    options = "1) steak\n2) burger"
    print(options)
    entree_selection = int(input("Pick one."))
    if entree_selection == 1:
        entree_choice = "steak"
        side_dish()
    elif entree_selection == 2:
        entree_choice = "burger"
        side_dish()


def side_dish():
    entree_choice = entree()
    print(f"You chose {entree_choice}.")
    print("Now choose your side.")
    options = "1) baked potato\n2) green beans"
    print(options)
    side_selection = int(input("Pick one."))
    if side_selection == 1:
        side_choice = "baked potato"
        dessert()
    elif side_selection == 2:
        side_choice = "green beans"
        dessert()


def dessert():
    entree_choice = entree()
    side_choice = side_dish()
    print(f"So far we have {entree_choice} and {side_choice}.")
    print("How about dessert?")
    options = "1) cake\n2) ice cream"
    print(options)
    dessert_selection = int(input("Pick one."))
    if side_selection == 1:
        dessert_choice = "cake"
        your_meal()
    elif side_selection == 2:
        dessert_choice = "ice cream"
        your_meal()


def your_meal():
    entree_choice = entree()
    side_choice = side_dish()
    dessert_choice = dessert()
    print(
        f'You will be having {entree_choice} with {side_choice} and {dessert_choice}')


entree()
side_dish()
dessert()
your_meal()
```

The issue for me is that ***function a*** is repeating over and over without ever running function b

To be honest, I've lost track of all the things I have tried. I've tried at least 10 things from YouTube and at least the same number from here.

Comment: You need to return your values. You're currently not returning anything. Effectively, add `return your_meal()`, or `return dessert()`. Currently they're all none.

Comment: Further, you're also rerunning your top level function inside `side_dish`. If you were to "step through" your program, you would ask for their entree, then you would get their answer. Great! Then you would ask their side_dish, but you would then literally ask for their entree _again_. You only need to do this once.

Comment: @spen.smith can you specify where to place the returns, because I have used them, and it hasn't changed my results at all. Obviously, I'm using them in the wrong place or the wrong way.  Remember, I'm coding with a few hours experience here.

As to the "rerunning your top level function inside side_dish" comment, I assume you're referring to the line "entree_choice = entree()" which I thought seemed strange, but that's how I saw a few people on YouTube do it. If I don't specify that there, how does side_dish get "entree_choice" from function entree?

Comment: Hey @Jace, I rephrased below. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: @spen.smith that's heading in the right direction, and a little confidence boosting, because that's sort of the train I was taking myself before YouTube took me down another path. The problem I was running into, and still run into with your selection is when trying to pass to multiple functions or in getting a function to receive from multiple other functions.

Comment: Hey Jace, there are two separate problems here. Basically, you're recalling Function A from within Function B. This creates an infinite loop. The second problem, is that you're not **returning** anything from your function calls. I've written an example towards the bottom to help with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function A is repeating because at the end of Function A, you call Function B, and at the beginning of Function B, you call Function A. Which restarts your loop.

Function B is always running, it just can't ever finish because you have requested that Function B always reruns Function A.

In order to not repeat, you cannot request `side_dish` to rerun `entree`.

```
def side_dish():
    entree_choice = entree() # this is the problem
    print(f"You chose {entree_choice}.")
    print("Now choose your side.")
```

Instead, pass the `entree_choice` as a variable into your `side_dish`.

```
def side_dish(entree_choice):
    print(f"You chose {entree_choice}.")
    print("Now choose your side.")
```

To continue the example, you would then create a dessert function which takes in both of your previous choices.

```
def dessert(entree_choice, side_choice):
    print(f"So far we have {entree_choice} and {side_choice}.")
    print("How about dessert?")
```

Which naturally gets us to the final function:

```
def your_meal(entree_choice, side_choice, dessert_choice):

    print(
        f'You will be having {entree_choice} with {side_choice} and {dessert_choice}')
```

---

With all of that being said, I would recommend a slightly different implementation. Basically, have a "controller". This thing controls all of the logic at one single level.

```
entree_choice = entree()
side_choice = side_dish()
dessert_choice = dessert()
print(f'You will be having {entree_choice} with {side_choice} and {dessert_choice}')
```

In order to accomplish this, two things:

1. Modify your underlying `entree` function to **not** ask about the side choice. Instead let the controller ask.
2. Return the entree that they chose.

```
def entree():
    options = "1) steak\n2) burger"
    print(options)
    entree_selection = int(input("Pick one."))
    if entree_selection == 1:
        entree_choice = "steak"
        return entree_choice
    elif entree_selection == 2:
        entree_choice = "burger"
        return entree_choice
```

Comment: This does help some. I actually did this while waiting for your kind response, because it was the other way I saw it done on YouTube.  This was how I originally tried in my game. But where this method gets me stuck is when we get to the third and/or fourth functions. How do I pass variables from multiple functions to a function.  i.e. how does dessert receive from both entree and side_dish?

Comment: Hey Jace, in order to get it to function the way you've written it, you will continue to pass those values through, increasing the "arity", which is the number of arguments supplied to a function.

Comment: Excellent. I was able to track that. It's working great on my side now.  That means I'm ready to go back to my more complicated game code and apply these concepts. Thank you for not being condescending, being helpful, and instilling confidence. Much appreciated.

Comment: You bet Jace. That's why we're here!

Comment: I am pleased to say that I was able to successfully edit my code with your "controller" incorporated as well.  The great thing is I can now do both methods.  Yay!

Comment: Yooo! That's incredible. Congrats Jace.

Answer (score 0):

What you're missing is the idea of the 'return value' of a function. Start by breaking your task into discrete units. Using your example of `your_meal`, the program will run the function `entree()` first and set the result of that function to the variable entree_choice. But for it to work, the function `entree` needs to have one (or several) `return 'steak'` or similar type statements. This is how the different parts of your program "communicate" with each other: by way of arguments and return values from functions.

Also note that if you call entree, and entree then calls side_dish and side_dish then calls entree, then the program will never stop looping (which is the problem you've described) as happening.